# Key error '% trans "{}" %' in custom tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I've created a simple tag to make adding tooltips more simple. I've create a templatetags folder with `__init__.py` and `html_tags.py`.

**html_tags.py**

```
from django import template
from django.utils.html import format_html

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def tooltip(text):
    return format_html('<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{% trans "{}" %}"><img src="{% static "icons/tooltip.png" %}"></img></a>'.format(text))
```

The problem is that it seems not work with `{% trans "text" %}` which I need.

This is the error:

> KeyError at /dashboard/alerts-settings/ '% trans "{}" %'

but I use format so tt should be `{% trans "text" %}` instead of `{% trans "{}" %}`.

So I tried to do this:

```
format_html('<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{% trans "'+text+'" %}}"><img src="{{% static "icons/tooltip.png" %}}"></img></a>')
```

It raises:

> Single '}' encountered in format string

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It because `format_html` only check + return your html string, is valid or not.

an example,

```
>>> format_html('<a href="">dada</a>')
'<a href="">dada</a>'
>>> 
>>> format_html('{% trans "foobar" %}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/to/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/html.py", line 106, in format_html
    return mark_safe(format_string.format(*args_safe, **kwargs_safe))
KeyError: '% trans "foobar" %'
>>>
```

2. Don't use template block inside python script.

I suggest you to using `ugettext_lazy`, `gettex`, or else.. [see more...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/), an example in your case;

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

@register.simple_tag
def tooltip(text):
    return format_html('<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="%(text)s">'
                       '<img src="/static/icons/tooltip.png"></img></a>' % {'text': _(text)})
```

Comment: This answer doesn't resolve the issue.

format_html(ugettext_lazy('{% if get==True %}'))

KeyError: u'% if get==True %'